# Why some researchers define $\ell_\infty^n:=\Bbb R^n$? Why this notation is used?

Tags: functional-analysis, notation, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am reading a paper where the author say "let $n\geq2$ and $\ell_\infty^n:=\Bbb R^n$ with the sup norm, like usual". Why is that notation usual?

I was asking that because, for me, $\ell_\infty=\{(x_j)\in\Bbb R^\Bbb N~|~\sup|x_j|<\infty\}$ and $\ell_\infty^n=\ell_\infty\times\cdots\times\ell_\infty$ $n$-times. So the dimension of $\ell_\infty^n$ would be $\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Superscripts need not mean powers. The sphere $S^n$  is not the $n$th power of anything. Neither is $L^2$ the square of $L^1$. In papers on dynamical systems, $f^n$ is more likely to be the $n$th iterate $f\circ \cdots\circ f$ than the $n$th power of $f$. Notation does not rule over us; we use whatever notation is convenient in a given context.

If someone works with finite-dimensional normed spaces a lot, they will use $\ell_p^n$ because it's a short and convenient notation. The superscript traditionally denotes the dimension of a manifold or a vector space, and we still have to put $p$ somewhere to indicate what norm it has, so it goes in the subscript. (And $\ell$ is probably by similarity with the function space $L_p$, where it comes from "Lebesgue integrable".)

On the other hand, I have little use for the $n$th Cartesian power of the space $\ell_\infty$ (it's trivially isometric to $\ell_\infty$). If I ever needed it, I'd write $(\ell_\infty)^n$.

Comment: I was asking that because, for me, $\ell_\infty=\{(x_j)\in\Bbb R^\Bbb N~|~\sup|x_j|<\infty\}$ and $\ell_\infty^n=\ell_\infty\times\cdots\times\ell_\infty$ $n$-times. So the dimension of $\ell_\infty^n$ would be $\infty$. Just added this to the question.

Comment: There is no reason for the exponent to.mean what you want it to.mean. The author is King of His Own Notation.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez That is trivial. I am not asking for the world be just like I want it to be, I am asking if there is interpretation/motivation (rather than own will) for this notation. If there is not, okay, that's the answer.

Comment: The interpretation is quite obvious. The $n$ denotes the dimension, the $\infty$ the norm, the $\ell$ is the usual name for spaces of sequences. That exponents are used for other things, like you remark in your comment above, is irrelevant.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Why don't they use simply $\Bbb R_\infty^n$? I think it's much better, but if they want to, what could I say...

Comment: Because they don't want to. At most, what you shoulduld do is write to the authors and ask them, but I suggest you don't. When you write your papers use your favorite notation —be sure, like they did, to make explicit what you use it for.

Comment: @Filburt One reason to use $\ell$ is that we can state theorems that are true for both real and complex scalars, like $(\ell_p^n)^* = \ell_q^n$, without writing them twice.